# Null-Pointer by findViewById

Tags: android

I have in my onCreate-Method a lot of findViewById. Some of them are parameter for objects I make in the onCreate-Method. Now I tried to make the findViewById-call in the Constructor of my Objects but i get a Null-Pointer.
How do I get these findViewByIds in my Object?

Comment: This seems worded a little strange. Can you show some of your code so we can get an idea of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use the current Activity, or pass the activity into your object since that method is only available for Activities.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor your object does not yet have a Context so findViewById will not work.  onCreate is the right place to put them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in your Context in your override, or else declare it static by using something like this:

```
static public activity = Activity.this;
```

This may be bad programming practice, however.  You may want to consider writing a general base class and implementing it as a "controller" for each of your views.

Hope this helped!